# WinEdt blank line text cause a DVI output spacing

Tags: spacing, winedt, dvi

I am using WinEdt 9 (with TexLive 2015) and I notice that if I leave a blank line between text line, this cause a unwanted spacing in my DVI/PDF output. I tried to do the same with a simple editor like Notepad, and no extra space occurred (like should be). To avoid this, it is enough to change some Document Setting on my WinEdt?

Comment: This is surely a duplicate, but I'm too tired to search. I really strongly recommend reading a basic introduction to TeX or LaTeX or whatever you are using. (I am guessing LaTeX, but obviously read an introduction to ConTeXt if you are using that.) Otherwise, things are going to be somewhat frustrating, I guess.

Comment: Or an introduction to TeX since you seem to be using that rather than LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

A blank line is a paragraph break. This is how you tell TeX that you want to start a new paragraph.

It doesn't matter which editor you use, what determines the output is just the content of the `.tex` file (and other files it loads e.g. the class you use etc.).

If you don't want a paragraph break, don't leave a blank line. If you really, really, really, really feel you must, then you can comment the blank line so TeX will ignore it.

```
%
```

The thing to understand here is that WinEDT is ***just an editor***. It has zilch to do with the output in the DVI or PDF you produce.

If you edit a `.tex` file in Notepad and then compile that with TeX, you will get a paragraph break. TeX doesn't care what you edit the file in. It will treat the source in precisely the same way regardless.

Neither TeX nor your editor are like WYSIWYG editors or word processors. You are editing source code for your final document. That's why the final document may not look anything like the contents of the `.tex` file.

Although you can use Notepad to edit the source of your document, when you compile that source, the result will be identical. However, the same source `.tex` may look different in different editors e.g. WinEDT probably highlights the syntax for you, whereas Notepad probably doesn't. But how it appears while editing makes no difference to the final DVI/PDF.